# php running multiple ffmpeg command

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I want to convert video files into different resolution using ffmpeg. Right now i can run only 1 ffmpeg command the 2nd ffmpeg command does not get execute.

```
shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -y -i \"$target_file\" -c:v libx264 -s:v 854x480 -c:a copy \"{$newFileName}\" > logfile.txt 2>&1");
shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -y -i \"$target_file\" -c:v libx264 -s:v 480x360 -c:a copy \"{$360FileName}\" > logfile.txt 2>&1");
```

how can i code the script so that it can compress the video into various different resolution such as 240p, 360p, 480p?

Edited code to output 3 video files?

```
shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -y -i \"$target_file\" -map 0 -c:v libx264 -s:v 854x480 -c:a copy \"{$newFileName}\" -map 0 -c:v libx264 -s:v 480x360 -c:a copy \"{$new360pFileName}\" -map 0 -c:v libx264 -s:v 854x480 -c:a copy \"{$240pFileName}\"   > logfile.txt 2>&1");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can outputs together, like this

```
shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -y -i \"$target_file\" -map 0 -c:v libx264 -s:v 854x480 -c:a copy \"{$newFileName}\" -map 0 -c:v libx264 -s:v 480x360 -c:a copy \"{$360FileName}\" > logfile.txt 2>&1");
```

Comment: what does -map 0 mean? if i wish to add more video resolution i need to add the command after -map 0? refer to my updated code above.

Comment: `-map 0` means process all streams in input. Not strictly necessary, but safer to put it. For each new resolution, start with `-map 0`.Check your scale values. For the 240p outout, you have scaled to 854x480.